# Is that a variable a Symbol, a Method, why does this have a colon and that doesn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inconsistent naming conventions in Rails are confusing me. It seems like the syntax is all over the place. Here are some examples:

Why are there commas in the migration below? And, why doesn't the keyword `default` have a colon before it? What is this `default` keyword, a method, or a variable, a symbol? What is that thing?:

```
add_column :zombies, :rotting, :boolean, default: false
```

Here is another example:

Why is `age` not `:age` (with a colon)? Why is `make_rotting` called with a "`:`" before it?

```
 class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
       before_save :make_rotting

   def make_rotting
      if age > 20
         self.rotting = true
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: To add to the answer below :default/default is the default value passed for the column if its not passed while its created.

Comment: You need to take the time to read through a [Ruby programming](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) book before trying to understand Rails. Your questions are all basics for the language, and are well explained by any Ruby tutorial. In addition to "[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)", check out "[why's (poignant) guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby can be hard for Java and PHP people. :)

In Ruby, not everything is what it appears to be. Take this, for example:

```
before_save :make_rotting
```

This is a method call, sure. But it's not the `make_rotting` method that is called. It's the `before_save` (`:make_rotting` is its parameter). This is a so-called hook in ActiveRecord. `before_save` will take a method name as a parameter and will dynamically call it when the moment comes.

```
if age > 20
```

Here `age` is a method call, not a symbol. It could be written as:

```
if age() > 20
```

but the parentheses are optional. And lastly:

```
add_column :zombies, :rotting, :boolean, default: false
```

This method takes four parameters, the last of which is a hash. The hash uses the new Ruby 1.9 syntax. Previously it would be written like this (with the colon in the right place, and all):

```
add_column :zombies, :rotting, :boolean, :default => false
```

You should read a good book on Ruby programming, instead of scraping pieces of knowledge from Stack Overflow posts. :)

Comment: And, while parenthesis are optional, many of us old-timers and veterans of many language wars, tend to add the parenthesis automatically, whether they are required or not. It's a code maintenance thing, done to avoid ambiguity during run-time.

Comment: +1 "You should read a good book on ruby programming, instead of scraping pieces of knowledge from stackoverflow posts."

Comment: @theTinMan: are you telling me that you, an old timer, would prefer `if age() > 20` over `if age > 20`? :)

Comment: If it's a function I'd prefer to see the empty parenthesis to differentiate `age` (a function) from `age` (a variable). During a maintenance cycle, if `age` (the function) was misbehaving, it'd take longer to identify it as a function. While Ruby style guides might take a different path, I'll continue to rant about it in code reviews. It's a privilege of age. :-)

Comment: @the Tin Man, re: "It's a code maintenance thing, done to avoid ambiguity during run-time". I think it warrants mentioning that the "ruby way" of *not* including parenthesis, to leave the ambiguity, is intentional, and is considered good-practice for future maintenance of the code. Sure, `age` is a variable, known in advance today, but it may be calculated based on a `birthday` tomorrow, so not bothering to specify whether it's a variable or a method is considered good for future-proofing.

Comment: @theTinMan: Modern IDEs are getting so smart nowadays that sometimes I even wonder, how strong a job security I have, soon the IDE will do all the job by itself  :)

Comment: I understand the "good practice for code maintenance" statement and why they make it, but I disagree with the reasoning. Coming from a C ->Perl background, I've seen too much code with ambiguity causing problems, either due to run-time problems, or worse, during the debugging of the run-time problems. I've been burned, and think parenthesis in code were added for a reason. :-)

Comment: LOL @SergioTulentsev, LONG LIVE VIM!

Comment: @theTinMan Emacs also likes parenthesis :)

Comment: re: "perl background". I refrain from starting a language holywar right here :)

Comment: BTW, a question: my dictionary says that "parenthesis" is singular and "parentheses" is the plural. But you guys are using singular form, why?

Comment: Why? Because we're ignorant programmers and typing fast. :-)

Comment: Why not just follow the syntax that was given to us from our fathers and grandfathers and great grandfathers a function f(x) is just intuitive. Its MATHHHHHH!!!! REALLY???!?! WOOOWW. Ruby Sucks!

Answer (score 3):

Three main things:

1. Methods in Ruby don't require parentheses around their arguments. `before_save` and `add_column` are methods, so `:make_rotting` is the argument to `before_save`.
2. Anything starting with a `:` is a symbol. Symbols are like strings, but they only get allocated in memory once no matter how many times you use the same symbol in your code. They're used for lots of things - very often as hash keys.
3. Ruby methods that take a hash as their last argument don't require `{}`'s around the hash.

So this:

```
add_column :zombies, :rotting, :boolean, default: false
```

could be rewritten as:

```
add_column(:zombies, :rotting, :boolean, {default: false})
```

Comment: "Symbols are just strings you can pass around but not change." No, they're not strings, but they seem similar, and are used in similar ways often. Symbols are good, and have many healthy benefits in Ruby code, so don't be afraid of them.